# Information Extraction

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, nltk, spacy

I am looking for steps/process to extract information from a Invoice using machine learning/NLP/Deep learning techniques. What will be the steps/process to be followed ?

The approach would need clarification on below

Suppose there are invoices from 2 Vendors, how a model needs to be created to extract the value mentioned for below fields? Will it have Keyword extraction ? Does custom NER needs to be implemented, if so how ? How should the training data be created for this ?

Invoice Number
Invoice Date
Invoice Amount
Address

Comment: This question is far too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpaCy to train your custom NER. There is a specific format of input that SpaCy requires that contains the start and end index of each entity and its label. You can refer to SpaCy documentation: https://spacy.io/usage/training

Comment: Thanks, I had referred to this. Is this the best option ? Are you aware of any other way to go about this ?

Comment: I have only tried SpaCy NER, the other popular option is Stanford NER. The fancier NER that I think can see context better is BERT-NER (https://github.com/kyzhouhzau/BERT-NER).